# GetFeatureInfo in OpenLayers only if the layer is visible

Tags: openlayers, getfeatureinfo

I'm using the following code in Open Layers 6, and it shows the feature info, even if the layer is not visible

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt){
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        var viewResolution = vista.getResolution();
        var url = wmsLayer3.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:25830', {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
        if (url) document.getElementById('info').data = url;
    });
```

How should it be modified to show the feature info only if the layer is visible?

Comment: You could insert `if (!wmsLayer3.getVisible()) return;` at the start of the function.

Comment: Beautiful! Could you please write it as answer so I can validate it?

Comment: This comment will be mostly for @Mike: Mike somehow prefers answering in comments and as a consequence many of his great answers (many with CodePen examples) get lost for general public. It's a pity but that's how it is. See the latest example of complete answer in comment with a CodePen example at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429687/openlayers-draw-custom-shapes-from-html-canvas.  I gave up asking him to change comments into answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the visibility of the layer in the callback function, and exit if not visible:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt){
        if (!wmsLayer3.getVisible()) return;
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        var viewResolution = vista.getResolution();
        var url = wmsLayer3.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:25830', {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
        if (url) document.getElementById('info').data = url;
    });
```

Comment: :-) :-) :-) :-) :-) :-)